# How to implement auto-save on a webapp

Tags: javascript

I am trying to incorporate this code

```js
var timeoutId;  
$('textarea').keypress(function () {
    if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/savecomment',
            data: { comment: $(this).val() }
        });
    }, 750);
});
```

from the tutorial [here](http://www.codetunnel.io/how-to-implement-autosave-in-your-web-app/) to implement auto-save in my web app. However, I am confused about two things.

1. Where exactly is the code being saved in this example? When I reload the page, the text I wrote is no longer there.
2. I tried to incorporate their example of this implementation into my code, but it did not work. The text box and the gray "no change" text above it appears fine, but this text does not change when I type. How could this be if I copied the HTML, CSS, and JS exactly as they are in the example?

Sorry for the elementary questions and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Also don't base a question on a link to an external site which could disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Because you probably did not implement the server-side, e.g. the `/savecomment` endpoint for the `$.ajax()` call.

I would argue that this is quite an over-engineered example and could easily be solved with  `localStorage`, could be as simple as this:

```js
// check if we have something to restore on page-load
$(window).on('load', function() {
    if ( localStorage.getItem('text') ) {
        $('textarea').val(localStorage.getItem('text'));
    }
});

$('textarea').on('input', function () {
    localStorage.setItem('text', $(this).val());
    
    // in a real browser you could verify it by
    // uncommenting the following line, does not work
    // in the sandbox this snippet runs in...
    
    console.log('Saved text: ', localStorage.getItem('text'));
});


$('form').on('submit', function() {
    alert('Actually save the text to the server via AJAX call');
    // you should then clear the saved text after you successfully saved
    // the content on the server
    localStorage.removeItem('text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="/savecomment">
    <textarea name="sometext"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Save To Server</button>
</form>
```

then, when the user is actually done, have a "Save" button that can be clicked, that actually sends the finished text to the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where is it saved?

It is saved in the app which runs in the /savecomment path. You need to implement  this endpoint.

2. Is it sufficient to produce html, css and js?

Not sufficient. You need to implement the server app which saves the comment too.